# Given two tables, how to find an average # of rows in the associated table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following two tables:

```
users [id, email, name]
hobbies [id, name]
hobbies_users [hobby_id, user_id]
```

My goal is to determine the AVG # of hobbies per user.

What would be the right way to structure this SQL query? Should I be using a LEFT JOIN? Appreciate a pointer in the right direction. Thank you

Comment: you mean the average for all the users?

Comment: Yes, the average number of hobbies per user.

Comment: Yes, you should use a LEFT JOIN. Make sure you use `IFNULL()` to convert the `NULL` for the users with no hobbies to `0`.

Comment: `IFNULL(COUNT(hobbies_users.hobby_id), 0)`

Comment: I don't see a way of answering the question without writing the code for you in full.

Comment: @Barmar, lol. you are almost there..go ahead

Comment: I would group by hobbies_users.user_ID for Barmar count and iiner join the user table to hobbies_users to get the name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `count()` and division.  If you want the average for users who have hobbies:

```
select count(*) * 1.0 / count(distinct user_id)
from hobbies_users;
```

If you want the average over all users, there are multiple ways, but I think I would go for:

```
select num_hobbies * 1.0 / num_users
from (select count(*) as num_hobbies from hobbies_users) hu cross join
     (select count(*) as num_users from users) u
```